# Move From Access To SQL Server: Best Calculation options?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, ssas

I am in the process of moving my Access database tables and update process onto SQL Server. I have been able to transfer the historical data and create tasks via SSIS to import the data regularly the issue is replicating the saved queries that were one in Access

For example I had a query that calculated multiple KPIs using SQl such as

```
SUM(Case when ThisField = 5 then 1 else 0))
```

However short of creating a query in SQL Server and saving it somewhere I cant seem to find a better answer.

I had considered using SSAS, that way all of these functions could be predefined however as the majority of this is simply on 1 table that proved difficult

Other users will need to access these queries, before they were stored within Access and could modify as they need but I am not so sure with SQL Server, what option would be best?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I really understand what you're asking for, but somehow computed columns come to mind. If aggregation is needed, look at indexed views.

Comment: I don't believe I can use aggregated context for computed columns though? That code in the above example is trying to return the total number of 5's in a particular field for the whole query, not just the row

Comment: Before I confuse things further, you're familiar with views and stored procedures, right?

Comment: I am quite new to SQL Server but those were the two options I was looking at however for both it almost feels like your are simply saving a query...is that correct? Views keeps reformatting my code (and its huge) so maybe a stored procedure

Comment: Simply put, stored procedures let you save code (like a function). Views do the same thing but they can only have a single SELECT, and when you use them it feels like you're reading from a table. It is your IDE that reformats your code - you can preserve your original format if you use a query window (text editor).

Comment: Actually I think this will work, been playing around with functions and although it may be complicated I could get users to specify the parameters which will 'customise' the code for them...for example do you want to include x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant comment yet, but I'll give you an "answer".  Stored procedures are the best way to "save" things and then you can create jobs to run them.  Basically

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourNewProcedureName
declare @Parameter as varchar(50) --if you need a parameter
as
Select * from yourtable
where ThisColumn = @Parameter
```

and then once created change the word CREATE to ALTER and execute a second time.  This way, you are now just altering the existing procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE YourNewProcedureName
declare @Parameter as varchar(50) --if you need a parameter
as
Select * from yourtable
where ThisColumn = @Parameter
```

Then,

```
execute YourNewProcedureName
```

in a step in a job, will trigger it to run on a schedule, should you need that functionality.  You can also use the proc name in SSRS to create reporting.

As for the access queries, I believe that unfortunately you are looking at a manual code conversion.  Finding someone that knows both syntaxes or learning the SQL syntax yourself are your best bet.  There are things SQL can do much better, particularly if you are on a newer version.

Have fun! Hope this helps!